# Does the transfer() method always try to transfer on behalf of the contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

Here's the code I've implemented. The goal is to faciliate an transaction between two users.

```
function transfer(address _to, uint amount) external {
IHEX(0x2b591e99afE9f32eAA6214f7B7629768c40Eeb39).transfer(_to,amount);
}
```

However, whenever I call this from one address trying to send some HEX to another, it says balance is too low. Both wallets have plenty of HEX, and after troubleshooting, I figured out it was trying to deduct from the contract's balance. Is there anyway to make this go from user to user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `transferFrom` method rather than transfer.

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20#methods